# Getting the first word in a String after quotation " (Java)

Tags: java, regex, find, quote

I have the following String:

```
String sentence = "this is my sentence \"course of math\" of this year";
```

I need to get the first word after a quote like this one `"`.
In my example I would get the word : course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative [`replaceAll` approach](http://ideone.com/ATnl9E):

```
String sentence = "this is my sentence \"course of math\" of this year"; 
System.out.println(sentence.replaceAll("(?s)[^\"]*\"(\\w+).*", "$1"));
// Or - if there can be a space after the first quote:
sentence = "this is my sentence \"   course of math\" of this year"; 
System.out.println(sentence.replaceAll("(?s)[^\"]*\"\\s*(\\w+).*", "$1"));
```

It returns `course` because the pattern grabs any characters up to the first `"` (with `[^"]*`), then matches the quote, then matches and captures 1+ alphanumeric or underscore characters (with `(\w+)`), and then matches any 0+ characters up to the end (with `.*`), and we replace it all with just the contents of Group 1.

Just in case someone wonders if a non-regex solution is also possible, here is one that does not support spaces between the first `"` and the word:

```
String sentence = "this is my sentence \"course of math\" of this year"; 
String[] MyStrings = sentence.split(" "); // Split with a space
String res = "";
for(int i=0; i < MyStrings.length; i++)  // Iterate over the split parts
{
    if(MyStrings[i].startsWith("\""))    // Check if the split chunk starts with "
    {
        res = MyStrings[i].substring(1); // Get a substring from Index 1
        break;                           // Stop the iteration, yield the value found first
    }
}
System.out.println(res);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/BqvMGP)

And here is another one that supports spaces between the first `"` and the next word:

```
String sentence = "this is my sentence \"   course of math\" of this year"; 
String[] MyStrings = sentence.split("\"");
String res = MyStrings.length == 1 ? MyStrings[0] :  // If no split took place use the whole string
    MyStrings[1].trim().indexOf(" ") > -1 ?          // If the second element has space
      MyStrings[1].trim().substring(0, MyStrings[1].trim().indexOf(" ")): // Get substring
      MyStrings[1];                                  // Else, fetch the whole second element
System.out.println(res);
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/IbBgKX)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :)  Please, is there any way this can work in case there is a space after the quote "  ... Exp :  \"    course of ...etc. ?

Comment: Yes, add `\\s*` after `"` in the regex solution: `sentence.replaceAll("(?s)[^\"]*\"\\s*(\\w+).*", "$1")`. See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/lQ7ZPt)**.

Answer (score 2):

That's really simple, Try this:

```
/"(\w+)/
```

And you can get expected word by using `$1`

- `"` matches the characters " literally
- `(` capturing group
- `\w+` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iA2zN7/1)

Comment: That was very fast +1

Comment: @anubhava Thank you buddy .. btw you are much faster than me in this kind of fields .. I seen you before `;-)`

Comment: This would break if string contains word characters outside ASCII (such as a or c with accent) Example string : this is a test "Akrapovičfg test string . Text will have to be normalized to ASCII (java has built in normalizers for that).